# set a custom post type to a taxonomy term programmatically in metabox

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, taxonomy, metabox

I have a Custom Post Type called `Movies` and it has a Custom Taxonomy called `Genres`. I also have 3 Terms under `Genres` called `['Action','Comedy','Horror']`

Can you please let me know how I can Get and Set associates the created Terms to the Custom Post Type from a Metabox on publishing the post?

```
function movie_genres_get_meta( $value ) {
    global $post;

    $field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
    if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {
        return is_array( $field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $field ) );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function movie_genres_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'movie_genres-movie-genres',
        __( 'Movie Genres', 'movie_genres' ),
        'movie_genres_html',
        'post',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
    add_meta_box(
        'movie_genres-movie-genres',
        __( 'Movie Genres', 'movie_genres' ),
        'movie_genres_html',
        'movirecpt',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'movie_genres_add_meta_box' );

function movie_genres_html( $post) {
    wp_nonce_field( '_movie_genres_nonce', 'movie_genres_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>

        <input type="checkbox" name="movie_genres_action" id="movie_genres_action" value="action" <?php echo ( movie_genres_get_meta( 'movie_genres_action' ) === 'action' ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
        <label for="movie_genres_action"><?php _e( 'Action', 'movie_genres' ); ?></label>   </p>    <p>

        <input type="checkbox" name="movie_genres_comedy" id="movie_genres_comedy" value="comedy" <?php echo ( movie_genres_get_meta( 'movie_genres_comedy' ) === 'comedy' ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
        <label for="movie_genres_comedy"><?php _e( 'Comedy', 'movie_genres' ); ?></label>   </p>    <p>

        <input type="checkbox" name="movie_genres_horror" id="movie_genres_horror" value="horror" <?php echo ( movie_genres_get_meta( 'movie_genres_horror' ) === 'horror' ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
        <label for="movie_genres_horror"><?php _e( 'Horror', 'movie_genres' ); ?></label>   </p><?php
}

function movie_genres_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['movie_genres_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['movie_genres_nonce'], '_movie_genres_nonce' ) ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['movie_genres_action'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_genres_action', esc_attr( $_POST['movie_genres_action'] ) );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_genres_action', null );
    if ( isset( $_POST['movie_genres_comedy'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_genres_comedy', esc_attr( $_POST['movie_genres_comedy'] ) );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_genres_comedy', null );
    if ( isset( $_POST['movie_genres_horror'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_genres_horror', esc_attr( $_POST['movie_genres_horror'] ) );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_genres_horror', null );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'movie_genres_save' );
```

Comment: When you register the taxonomy you should get the meta box automatically. You shouldn’t need to do anything.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for reply but can you please explain this a little bit more?